# Use Wordpress to Build Twitter, eBay, or Amazon

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

It's my second ignorant question for today, this one even more ignorant than the first.

Why wouldn't you use Wordpress to build Twitter, eBay, Amazon, or [you name any other "application" type website]?

There are some big name websites using Wordpress (supposedly) like Network Solutions. It's unclear to me how much of their website actually runs on Wordpress. Most of these sites appear to be more news or blog oriented. I'm guessing they use Wordpress to post "static" content but probably build other application features outside of wordpress. For example, do you think Network Solutions domain lookup and purchasing features are built in Wordpress?

But the real question here I guess is what type of website would you build in Wordpress, Concrete5, Joomla, or Drupal? It seems like a really stupid question but would you build a custom web app using CMS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMS' are really good if you require ease of use, 'simple' customisability, or (in the case of wordpress) are constantly updating. Services such as eBay or Twitter wouldn't make sense on one of these platforms as there would be a lot of proprietary code in order to make there service work and be unique - this is what CMS' fall down on. You rely on people (or yourself) to build plugins to extend the original functionality. With a ground up website, you lose all the 'flab' (i.e. excess code and functionality that you may never use) and have a much more managable system.

Behind all the sites you mention would be some kind of in-house built CMS - it just wouldn't make sense for these companies to use publically available systems.